# All of site records are deleted from my tables

Tags: mysql, database, records

what could delete all the records from all the tables in a database. I have a site created on codeignitor. The site was working fine till couple of days back.

I am using MySQL

All records that are driven from the database is gone! On checking the PHPmyAdmin MYSQL I found that all the tables needed for the site are empty 0 records.

Is this possible to happen by itself?  can a code delete all the data from all tables at once?
or should I suspect hacking of the site?

the hard coded parts of the site are all ok and functioning.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't take precautions against SQL injections it is very possible someone deleted this records using a SQL injection through your wesite.  After restoring your backup (you do backup, right?) You will need to look through your queries for vulnerailties. At the very least make sure you're escaping user input. Idealy, you'll switch to parameterized queries which. Dscape queries by default.

Answer (score 0):

Your site may have been vulnerable to SQL injection if you had anywhere that you allowed form inputs, performed calculations on those inputs, and made changes to the database.  If not properly escaped, the input could have contained malicious commands which deleted or truncated information in your database.

More information about SQL injection: http://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: The only input areas of the site are in 1)  Contact Form   2) Renting request form (where a text area is available for a message)  3) the CMS username and password.  but none of these are editing any database.. 1 & 2 and sending emails and 3 is accessing the CMS.  Where else should I look.. could there be any other way of hacking the database that I am not aware of?